# Proper use of DifferentDatabaseScope when it's within another SessionScope

Tags: castle-activerecord

I have the following code (simplified for brevity)

```
[ActiveRecord(Table = "[Order]"),
Serializable]
public class Order : ActiveRecordLinqBase<Order>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
            //Other properties omitted for brevity

    private IList<Reading> _readings;
    [HasMany(Inverse = true, Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.All)]
    public virtual IList<Reading> Readings
    {
        get { return _readings; }
        set
        {
            _readings = value;

            DoPropertyChanged(() => this.Readings);
        }
    }
}



using (new SessionScope(FlushAction.Never) {
    Order o = _repository.GetOrder(OrderId);
    bool result = ShowReadings(this, o);
    if (result) s.Flush();
}


bool ShowReadings(Window owner, Order o) {
    //populate a datagrid with Reading objects from Order
    this.Readings = Order.Readings  //datagrid binds to Readings property of the form

    if (cbxHistoricalChecked) {
        using(new DifferentDatabaseScope(SomeOtherConnectionString)) {
            //bind datagrid to historical readings
            this.Readings = GetHistoricalReadings(Order.OrderId);
        }
    }

    if (SignedOff) {
        using(var t = new TransactionScope()) {
           //update some properties on the Order
           t.VoteCommit();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So what I'm doing is having a SessionScope open while the readings form is open, and flushed once it is closed.  If the user wants to view historical readings for the order, I have to open a different database for the historical readings.
Things work fine as long as I don't open the DifferentDatabaseScope, but when I do, the creation of a new TransactionScope fails:
Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Scopes.ScopeMachineryException {"Tried to unregister a scope that is not the active one"}

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do, and if so what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: moved on to EntityFramework, never found a solution for this.